# selenium wrong xpath with li c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

```
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/live/");
        string myTime = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[@class='wrapper']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='contentdiv']/" +
                                                    "div[@id='middle']/" +
                                                    "div[@id='container']/" +
                                                    "div[@id='content']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='content clear-block bet_a_c']/" +
                                                    "div[@id='livediv']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='selected--sport--block']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='view-wrapper']/" +
                                                    "ul[@class='sport--list']/" +
                                                    "li[@class='sport--block']/" +
                                                    "ul[@class='category--list--block']/" + 
                                                    "li[@class='category--block sp_1']/" +
                                                    "ul[@class='events--list']/" +
                                                    "li['']/" +
                                                    "ul[@class='event--head-block']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='event--head']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='event--short--info']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='time--block']/" + 
                                                    "div[@class='headerdiv']/" +
                                                    "div[@class='event--timer']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
        Console.WriteLine(myTime);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Hello everybody. I just started to learn selenium and collided with the issue of finding an element. I want to get the value of the timer, but it is unsuccessful. I bet my problem is that I am making mistake in XPath at line

```
 "li['']/" +
```

Do you have an idea how can I get it in a correct way? 
I am going to get value '45:00'
from `<div class="event--timer">45:00</div>`

Oh, by the way when I start debugging my project Chrome browser starts twice. I don't know why, but it happens each time.
Thank you in advance for any suggests.

```
   <body class="tm_18 uk " data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" style="">
  <noscript>
     <div id="noscript">Будь ласка, увімкніть JavaScript у вашому браузері!</div>
  </noscript>
  <a id="topsite" name="topsite"></a>
  <div id="dialog" title=""></div>
  <div id="dialogPre">
     <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
  </div>
  <div id="full_vers" style="display:none;">
     <button class="close" rel="fullcls">close</button>
     <div class="full_blok">
        <p>
           Вы перешли на полную версию сайта.
           Хотите запомнить Ваш выбор для следующего посещения сайта?
           <button rel="fullyes" class="btn-chs">Так</button>
           <button rel="fullno" class="btn-chs">Ні</button>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div class="cl"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="header">
        <div class="headerdiv">
           <div class="logo">
              <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/bets/" title=""><img src="./Фаворит спорт - Зробити ставку. Компанiя_files/blank.gif" alt="" id="logo"></a>
           </div>
           <div id="counterPl" class="counter--playing" style="display:none;"></div>
           <div class="head--block">
              <div class="nav--block" style="overflow: visible;">
                 <ul class="nav--level--1">
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/bets/" class="service_id_1">
                       <span class="">СПОРТ</span>
                       </a>
                       <button class="sub--level--yes"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                       <ul class="nav--level--2">
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/bets/results/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Результати</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="javascript:openPopup(&#39;12345&#39;,&#39;http://stats.betradar.com/s4/?clientid=509&amp;language=ukr&#39;);" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Статистика</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div id="vip-dropdown">
                          <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
                       </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/live/" class="service_id_1 active">
                       <span class="">Live</span>
                       <b>159</b></a>
                       <button class="sub--level--yes"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                       <ul class="nav--level--2">
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/live/calendar/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Календар Live</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="javascript:openPopup(&#39;123459&#39;,&#39;http://ls.betradar.com/ls/livescore/?/favoritbetua/ukr/page&#39;);" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Результати Live</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/favoritsporttv/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Прямі трансляції</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/virtual/" class="service_id_1">
                       <span class="">Віртуальний спорт</span>
                       </a>
                       <button class="sub--level--yes"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                       <ul class="nav--level--2">
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/vfl/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="null">Віртуальна футбольна ліга</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/ncup/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Кубок націй</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/vto/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальний теніс</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/vbl/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальний баскетбол</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual-games/?category_id=36334" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="new">Конячі перегони</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual-games/?category_id=36335" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="new">Футбол</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual-games/?category_id=36338" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="new">Коняча Рулетка</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual-games/?category_id=36339" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="new">Настільний теніс</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual/?category_id=1559" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальний футбол</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/virtual/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="new">Віртуальний спорт від Inspired</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual/?category_id=35937" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальні Мотогонки</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual/?category_id=35938" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальні Велоперегони</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual/?category_id=35939" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальні Скачки</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual/?category_id=35941" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальні Собачі перегони</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/virtual/?category_id=36097" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Віртуальна Формула 1</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/casino/" class="service_id_1">
                       <span class="new">Казино</span>
                       </a>
                       <button class="sub--level--yes"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                       <ul class="nav--level--2">
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/casino/cashrace/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="new">Гонка призових</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/casino/rating/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Рейтинг</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/casino/winners/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Переможці</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/live-casino/" class="service_id_1">
                       <span class="">Казино LIVE</span>
                       </a>
                       <button class="sub--level--yes"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                       <ul class="nav--level--2">
                          <li>
                             <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/live-casino/tips-and-strategy/" class="service_id_1">
                             <span class="">Поради та Стратегія</span>
                             </a>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
                 <button class="menu_button">
                    <div class="toggle_switch"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="nav-dop-menu">
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/tvloto/" class="service_id_1">
                       <span class="">ТВ ЛОТО</span>
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="https://www.favorit.com.ua/uk/page/main_promo/" class="service_id_1">
                       <span class="">Акції</span>
                       </a>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="user--block">
              <script id="usermessagewc" type="text/x-jsrender">
                 <div class="u_msg_tci">
                    Total critical/important messages <span rel="count">0</span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="u_msg_txt">
                    [[:text]]
                 </div>
              </script>
              <script id="usermessage" type="text/x-jsrender">
                 <div class="u_msg_dt">[[:dt_sesent]]</div>
                 <div class="u_msg_bl">
                    <div class="u_msg_subject">[[:subject]]</div>
                    <div class="u_msg_bd">[[:message]]</div>
                 </div>
              </script>
              <div id="user-block">
                 <div data-reactroot="" class="loginbgL">
                    <div class="loginbgR">
                       <div class="loginicon">
                          <div id="nauth">
                             <div class="not_login">
                                <a class="loginpagecl but-blue-1"><span>Увійти</span></a>
                                <div class="but-red-1" rel="mdlreg"><span>Реєстрація</span></div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <script src="./Фаворит спорт - Зробити ставку. Компанiя_files/loginUser.js.download" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second--menu">
           <div class="settings--block">
              <div id="timeplace" class="times_place">
                 <div data-reactroot="" class="times">
                    <p>20:20 (UTC +3)</p>
                    <div></div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="contentdiv">
        <div id="middle">
           <div id="container">
              <div id="content">
                 <div class="content clear-block bet_a_c">
                    <div class="badwe" style="display:none;">
                       <div class="entire">
                          <div class="close"></div>
                          <div class="lst-err">
                             <ul>
                                <li>Unknown error</li>
                             </ul>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="scenter"></div>
                    <div id="video_player"></div>
                    <div id="video_modal_auth"></div>
                    <div id="livediv" class="livediv">
                       <div data-reactroot="" class="selected--sport--block">
                          <div class="message--widget">
                             <div class="message--content new--user">
                                <i class="fa"></i><!-- react-text: 5 -->Новий користувач?<!-- /react-text --><span>Зареєструйтесь</span><b>та отримайте бонус ''Ставка без ризику'' до 500 грн!</b>
                             </div>
                             <div class="close--buton"><span>Закрити</span><i class="fa"></i></div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- react-empty: 11 -->
                          <div class="view-wrapper">
                             <ul class="sport--list">
                                <li class="sport--block">
                                   <div class="sport--head sp--bg sp_1 head--folding folding--open">
                                      <i class="sporticon sp_1"></i>
                                      <span>
                                         <!-- react-text: 25 -->Футбол<!-- /react-text --><u>83</u>
                                      </span>
                                      <b>Показати все</b>
                                   </div>
                                   <ul class="category--list--block">
                                      <li class="category--block sp_1">
                                         <div class="caterory--head">
                                            <div class="outcomes--name">
                                               <div class="category--name"><i class="sporticon sp--color sp_1"></i><span>Футбол | Іспанія | Ла Ліга</span></div>
                                               <ul class="count--label count-0 outcome-count-3">
                                                  <li title="1">1</li>
                                                  <li title="X">X</li>
                                                  <li title="2">2</li>
                                               </ul>
                                               <ul class="count--label count-1 outcome-count-3 has-param">
                                                  <li title="1">1</li>
                                                  <li>Фора</li>
                                                  <li title="2">2</li>
                                               </ul>
                                               <ul class="count--label count-2 outcome-count-3 has-param">
                                                  <li title="Б">Б</li>
                                                  <li>Тотал</li>
                                                  <li title="М">М</li>
                                               </ul>
                                               <div class="close--category"></div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <ul class="events--list">
                                            <li>
                                               <div class="event--head-block">
                                                  <u></u>
                                                  <div class="event--head event-has-description">
                                                     <div class="event--short--info">
                                                        <div class="event--line--position"><span>3371</span><b>1489</b></div>
                                                        <div class="time--block">
                                                           <div class="event--timer">45:00</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="event--result--type--name">П2</div>
                                                     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with below xpath

```
"/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/ul/li/ul/li/ul/li/div/div/div/div[2]/div"
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simple `//div[@class='event--timer']` ?

```
string myTime = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='event--timer']")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: I am not able to use this way. cuz there are a few classes "event--timer".

Comment: @the-vee You didn't tell about that. What timer do you want to check? Just use something like this: `//div[@class='event--timer']` or use more complicated expression

Comment: Did I understand correctly that '//' - this allows to look for "event--timer" everywhere, but deeper than path before?

Comment: Oh, you are from Russia, aren't you?

Comment: It will search everywhere. If you want to search deeper than current node you need to use relative path `.//div[@class="your_class"]`

Comment: Yes, I'm from Russia

Comment: Вау, я из Украины. Спасибо большое за ответ. я не нашел как отправить личное сообщение. Скажи, пожалуйста, можно ли с тобой связаться например в Скайпе? я не буду надоедливым, у меня просто есть пара вопросов, и я вижу что ты разбираешься. Спасибо.

Comment: You can use sites like [Freelancer](https://freelancer.com) or [Upwork](https://upwork.com)